# How can I backup an iOS 5 Beta 5 device?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, iphone, ios

I'm trying to backup my iOS 5 beta 5 device, but when I installed iTunes 10 beta 5, my Windows 7 computer doesn't let me run it saying that it expired. I don't want to upgrade through the device because upgrading from beta 5 to beta 6 forced many of my friends to hard-reset their devices and lose their data.

I just want to get my photos off the device, I don't really care about anything else.

Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

I installed iTunes 10 beta 5 on my mac machine and for some reason it worked. Still i couldn't get the photos off until I used iPhone Explorer. All Backed up now! :)